# Development "workflow" question using document-based storage

Tags: nosql, ravendb

This question is generic to any document-based storage, but at the moment I am using RavenDB.

Often I have had to do things in a hurry and test new UI tweaks by modifying the data. It's easy enough in the days of SQL Server - whip up Management Studio, a few Update queries and such, and I have new data to test UI changes.

What's the best practice when using document-based storage? I know RavenDB has the HTTP mode but I noticed it hung quite a fair bit. I keep getting the prolonged "Loading..." status.

What's everyone doing to make data tweaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plan for RavenDB is to have a Silverlight tool that will allow you to do a lot of the things that Management Studio allows. See [here](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/10/11/how-should-the-ravendb-ui-look-like-there-is-a.aspx) and [here](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/12/01/a-first-look-at-the-new-ravendb-ui.aspx) for more details

The current admin web pages in Raven are a bit basic, hence the need for something more advanced.

Comment: That's fantastic...I noticed in the 2nd post you listed there Ayende mentioned there was to be a release of it in a week or so. That was back in early 2010. I'm looking around to see where that was released...

Comment: That posts data is the 1st Dec 2010, not the 12th Jan 2010 ;-)